# Implementing Ruby's PG::TypeMapByOid

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

Does anybody know of a tutorial on how to implement a typemap for Ruby's Postgresql connection? I.e. how to create a PG::TypeMapByOid class? The documentation that I can find is pretty sparse and doesn't give any examples.